# delete rows and return an id of the deleted rows

Tags: mysql, sql

is it possible to delete a row and return a value of the deleted row?

example
`DELETE FROM table where time <= -1 week
SELECT all id that were deleted`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8602422/2908724

Comment: @bishop thanks bud, but that one looks like it will only work for the last deleted row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to control the operations in the database, you could consider to use JOURNAL tables. There's a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484714/how-to-store-datas-change-history) in SO about this.

They are a mirrored table, usually populated by a trigger with the operation performed (update, delete). It stores the "old values" (the current values you can always get from the main table).

If implemented so, you could then SELECT from the journal table and have exactly what you needed.

Trying to give you an example:

Table USER

```
CREATE TABLE USER (
   INT id,
   VARCHAR name
)
```

Table USER_JN

```
CREATE TABLE USER_JN (
    INT id,
    VARCHAR name,
    VARCHAR operation
)
```

Then, for every operation you can populate the USER_JN and have a history of all changes (you should not have constraints in it).

If you delete, your `operation` column would have the `delete` value and you could use your select to check that.

It's not exactly "selecting the deleted row", but a way to make it possible.

Hope it's somehow useful.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I think I'll go with this route.

Comment: Nice. This approach is good ti audit the system as well. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT id FROM table WHERE time <= -1 week

and then simply

DELETE FROM table WHERE time <= -1 week

Comment: Thanks for the info bud, but I was wondering if there was a way to do it in one line?

Comment: Sure, call a stored proc. One line.

Comment: I am not an expert in them but the only thing i can think of is to use a ["trigger"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers.html) to store the info

Comment: Well triggers are for auto running on insert update delete. So if that is not the expected behavior then don't do that. You can however do an Event that fires on a schedule, like cron, but baked into mysql without cron. See [one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37901661) and [two](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32508935)

Answer (score 0):

I would not search non indexed column twice. You should use a variable like:

SELECT id INTO @tID FROM table WHERE time <= -1 week;

DELETE FROM table WHERE id = @tID

You may then use the variable @tID as you wish.